# Statistics function for Lua?

Tags: math, lua, statistics

I'm trying to calculate a Student-t probability. I really need the incomplete beta function for this, but I can't find any good function in Lua. Does it exist?

I've ported over the code from Numerical Recipes in C, and it works, but it's not open source license. I need something with a real license, like GPL, MIT, etc.

Comment: Don't know for Lua but if you can do the port C -> Lua yourself I'd have a look at the [Cephes mathematical library](http://www.netlib.org/cephes/). I don't know their exact license but I know that their code has been used a lot in other open source libraries with licenses ranging from GPL to BSD/MIT-style and they have a incomplete beta.

Comment: scilua.org have something like that

Answer (score 0):

There's also Apophenia, at http://apophenia.info/ . It doesn't yet have Lua bindings, but I'd even be willing to work with you on developing one. It's plain C and its only complication for binding is the setup for variadic functions. Even this is not especially complicated; just push a lot of extra nils onto the stack as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Lua Fun is a high-performance practical programming library designed for LuaJIT tracing just-in-time compiler. The library affords a set of extra than 50 programming primitives usually determined in languages like Standard ML, Haskell, Erlang, JavaScript, Python and even Lisp.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).